# Change return type to 'T' errror

Tags: kotlin, generics, kotlin-coroutines, android-mvvm

I override this function from **ViewModelProvider.Factory** but I get an error with the generic return type `T`. Why?

```java
class NewsViewModelProviderFactory(
    val newsRepository: NewsRepository) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return NewsViewModel(newsRepository) as T
    }
}
```

Comment: And what error do you get? I don't have the Android SDK handy, so seeing the exact error in the question would be quite helpful.

Comment: also what's the function you're overriding?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the issue comes from the supertype of your type parameter `T`—that is, `ViewModel?`. According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory#create(java.lang.Class)), `create` is declared in `ViewModelProvider.Factory` as

```kotlin
open fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T
```

Notice that it says `<T : ViewModel>`, not `<T : ViewModel?>`. This means that any consumer of a `ViewModelProvider.Factory` expects the `create` function to return a *non-null* `ViewModel`. However, the `create` function you've written could return null.

If you changed your function to

```kotlin
override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
    return NewsViewModel(newsRepository) as T
}
```

that should alleviate the issue.